# How to create Right side menu frame

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

This Below red mark image is right side panel of my page , I want to open this panel when click the "check Text" Button ,Also I am straggling to design the dropdown list (Spelling mistake, Synonym, plane language ,usage, warning) this all are list how can I design this code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsQy6.png)

my code, For this side panel

```
<Frame Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="9*"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">


                                <Label  Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Correction}" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"></Label>

                                <Button  Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.CancleButoon}" Style="{StaticResource CancelButton}" Padding="0,0,10,20" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start"></Button>
                                <Button  Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.AcceptButton}" Style="{StaticResource AcceptButton}" Padding="5,0,0,20" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" ></Button>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <BoxView BackgroundColor="#F0F0F0" HeightRequest="2" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></BoxView>
                        </Grid>
                        <StackLayout>

                            <!-- DROP DOWN CODE-->

                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
```

Comment: Hello Developer Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

About "dropdown list" in iOS, there is no such control like "dropdownlist" in iOS. Generally, we use UIPickerView to select items (i.e., the control "Picker" in XAML).

If you still want to implement a dropdownlist-like control, you can implement it through "a combination of controls". You can check [an answer I posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67412655/8335151).

It should be noted that the control used in the answer is "UIPickerView". You can try to replace it with "UITableView" or any control you want to use.

So you can show the selected item in a UITextField (if needed). And display the items for selection in the "UITableView".

Comment: Is There any another way to implement this this view

Comment: @priyankapawar Because your dropdown list has to implement a specific function, I'm afraid you need to write your own code to  achieve the control combination.